# bash script copy output from set -x to file, called from within script rather than using tee

Tags: bash, ssh

I am wondering if there is a way to write `set -x` output to a file from within a script, rather than call a `tee` from the command prompt.

For example, I usually use `myScript.sh 2>&1 | tee mylog.log`  form the command prompt. This copies the set -x as I expect to the log file.

Is there a way to internalise this within `myScript.sh` so I can set it as a flag to be turned off if I do not need to debug. running only `myScript.sh` from the command prompt.

thx
Art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your script place this line at top:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $1 == "debug" ]] && { exec 2>err.txt; set -x; }

# rest of the script
```

Now when you call your script as:

```
./myScript.sh debug
```

You will get a file created as `err.txt` containing output of `set -x` (with other error, if any)